# Unable to get the balance sheet for the particular group of users. how can i be doing it

Tags: mysql, sql

```
user_id  created_at       status       amount
_____________________________________________
10196   31-08-2019 15:38  billcreated  21900
10196   05-09-2019 05:40  billpaid     43800
10196   15-12-2019 15:54  billcreated  11200
10205   15-03-2019 16:02  billcreated  2700
10205   31-03-2019 16:02  billcreated  27000
10205   23-04-2019 09:54  billpaid     3000
```

to get this table i used the query as below

```
select id,user_id,created_at,status,amount
from settlementdata
order by user_id,STR_TO_DATE(created_at, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i');
```

but now I want to get the table as below

```
user_id  created_at       status       amount  balance
______________________________________________________
10196   31-08-2019 15:38  billcreated  21900   21900 (as no previous records exits)
10196   05-09-2019 05:40  billpaid     43800   -21900 (balance - paid amount i.e 21900-43800)
10196   15-12-2019 15:54  billcreated  11200   -10700 (balance + bill created amount i.e -21900+11200)
10205   15-03-2019 16:02  billcreated  2700    2700 (as no previous records exits)
10205   31-03-2019 16:02  billcreated  27000   29700 (as 2700+27000) 
10205   23-04-2019 09:54  billpaid     3000    26700 (as 29700-3000)
```

for this i used a query as below

```
select id, user_id,created_at,status, amount, sum(
    case user_id
        when lag(user_id) over(order by id) = user_id and status = "billcreated"
        then amount
        when lag(user_id) over(order by id) = user_id and status = "billpaid"
        then amount*(-1)
        else 0
        end ) from (select id,user_id,created_at,status,amount from settlementdata
                    order by user_id,STR_TO_DATE(created_at, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i')
                    limit ) as T;
```

but still I am unable to get the resulted tab rather I got an error message as 
UNKNOWN_CODE_PLEASE_REPORT: You cannot use the window function 'lag' in this context.

Any help that i can get for the same is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your MySQL version.

Comment: mysql version what i am using over here is 8.0

Comment: On a side note: `STR_TO_DATE(created_at, ...)`??? Are you really storing the datetime as a string in your database? Don't! If this is really the case, change the table and store the datetime as `DATETIME`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2270762/thorsten-kettner i got the data as string format so simply calculating the balance. Rather i will change in db too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *, SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'billcreated' 
                   THEN amount 
                   ELSE -amount 
                   END) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id 
                              ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(created_at, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i') ASC) balance
FROM settlementdata
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/10138734/akina thanks it solved.

Comment: @Abhipsa Patro: If you want to address a particular user, just use the at sign, as I am doing right now, instead of pasting their profile URL.

Answer (score 1):

You want a running total (`SUM(...) OVER (ORDER BY ...)`) where the amount is considered positive for a status = 'billcreated' and negative for status = 'billpaid':

```
with fixedsettlementdata as -- bad data model fix
(
  select
    id,
    user_id, 
    str_to_date(created_at, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i') as created_at,
    status,
    amount
  from settlementdata
)
-- actual query
select
  id, user_id, created_at, status, amount,
  sum(case when status = 'billcreated' then amount else -amount end)
      over (partition by user_id order by created_at) as balance
from fixedsettlementdata
order by user_id, created_at;
```